# How can I use Flowtype and eslint with Vue/Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, eslint, flowtype, nuxt.js

I'm trying to set Flowtype with eslint and Vue.js/Nuxt.js for both template and script.

I installed flow and I get good feedback in Atom, both from flow and eslint (yay) and prettier-atom works like a charm... after hours of trying since I never really played with those before.

Now I would like to know if:

1) I missed a configuration

2) it's possible to make flow not report `Unexpected token @` in my Vuejs with a config or a package

3) Is it possible to make Atom/eslint/flow report an error if my `@click="something"` function is ok (folllow the rules) for example, or if a variable in `data()` is never used in the template or the script, etc

For reference, I first manage to make everything work with prettier-atom and now I'm trying to add Vue/Nuxt support. I followed [this link](https://alligator.io/vuejs/components-flow/) to set it up.

devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.46.3",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-flow": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.22.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype-errors": "^3.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "prettier": "^1.12.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.1"
  },
```

eslintrc:

```
root: true,
"parser": "babel-eslint",

"plugins": [
  "html",
  "flowtype",
  "prettier"
],
settings: {
  flowtype: {
    onlyFilesWithFlowAnnotation: false
  }
},
"extends": [
  "vue"
],

parserOptions: {
  ecmaVersion: 6,
  ecmaFeatures: {
    unicodeCodePointEscapes: true,
    globalReturn: true,
    jsx: true
  }
},
"globals": {
  "axios": true
},
"env": {
  "browser": true,
  "node": true,
  "commonjs": true,
  "es6": true
},
```

I omitted the rules because I have all the rules and their descriptions while I'm figuring out what I want.

babelrc:

```
{
   "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-flow",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"
  ]
}
```

My "test" code:

```
<template>
  <p>I'm made with Flow and a bunch of other cool stuff! {{ defined }}</p>
  <a @click="actionDefined">Submit this {{ NotDefined }}.</a>
  <a @click="actionUndefined">Looks like this one won't work.</a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created() {
    console.log(randomThing)
  },
  data() {
    return {
      defined: "boop!",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async actionDefined() {
      console.log("yay")
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

I would really appreciate your help,
Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to quickly say: I'm not sure Flow can handle that sort of templating code. See my (short) answer to another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49756309/1234433 . I'm absolutely not a Vue expert, but I'm pretty sure there's another way where it works better for Typescript and/or Flow.

Comment: You can use `wemake-vue-template`. It comes with `flow`, `nuxt` and other goodies: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-vue-template/blob/master/template/.flowconfig

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768727/how-to-add-flow-flowtype-support-in-nuxt/50109174#50109174

Comment: Thanks for your help! I m,ad eit work, although it's sometimes buggy a little.